# mdadm Raid5 gives spares missing events

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I successfully built up a raid5 array on Debian testing (Wheezy). As the man pages and further tell, the array would be created as an out-of-sync array with just a new spare injected to be repaired.
That worked fine.
But after the rebuild process, I get daily messages on missing spares, but the array should be raid5 over 3 discs *without* spares.
I think I only need to tell mdadm that there is -- and should be -- no spare, but how to?

`mdadm -D` gives

```
Active Devices:  3
Working Devices: 3
Failed Devices:  0
Spare Devices:   0
```

and `/proc/mdstat` reads

```
md1: active raid5 sda3[0] sdc3[3] sdb3[1]
##### blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open the /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf file, find the line that begins with `ARRAY /dev/md1` and remove the line immediately following which states 'spares=1'. Then restart mdadm service.

If you did a `mdadm --examine --scan` to retrieve the array definitions while the md1 array was still rebuilding, one partition was seen as spare at that moment.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I'm wondering, how the line got there. I know, that on building up (resulting in a rebuilding state) the has one spare - but after successfully rebuilding that line should be automatically removed, shouldn't it?  Anyhow - after manually commenting out the line it is working the way I want it to. Thanks!

Comment: @Bastian Ebeling: Many tutorials include `mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` in their instructions, just after the array creation (which is still rebuilding), so it includes an extra spare.